# Why can't find or install home module in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and is learning it from a youtube video. In the video the tutor does this
`from home import views`. Now when i try to do the same thing i get an error saying "Unresolved reference home". So i tried installing home using pip installer but is constantly getting the following error:-

```
Collecting uwsgi>=2.0
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\clash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gpajfqiw\uwsgi_5085974451e542118156b6196d19b2cf\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          import uwsgiconfig as uc
        File "C:\Users\clash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gpajfqiw\uwsgi_5085974451e542118156b6196d19b2cf\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
          uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
      AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Can somebody please tell me why this is happening and what is the solution to this error. I tried using cmd, windows powershell and vscode terminal but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Probably `home` is the name of the app or the project. If you can share your related code community can help you out